# What is the shelf life of vermouth?

Tags: storage-lifetime, alcohol

I like the occasional Negroni or Manhattan, but I'm not a heavy drinker. As far as I'm concerned liquor is pretty much immortal, but what's the rule on vermouth?

Comment: Might be a better fit on https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ but pretty longer than you will live

Comment: The oldest wine ever drunk by a human without severe side effects was an archaeologist trying Roman wine that did not turn into vinegar... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened, at room temp: A week or two without serious flavor changes.
Opened, but kept in the fridge: a month, at least.  (I'm still working my way through a bottle of dry vermouth with no noticeable degradation in flavor in ~3 months, ymmv of course).
Unopened: A year+ at room temp.

Source: [Serious Eats experiment](https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/07/best-way-to-store-vermouth-for-cocktails-fridge-vs-winesaver-rebottling.html)

Comment: Vermouth turning to vinegar? 